# hdfview doesn't open files on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

I've installed hdfview in Ubuntu 17.04.

The application is running but it is not opening hdf files.

I have also installed openjdk-8-jdk.

This worked in 16.04... what could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: More details are needed, how did you install? what error is produced when opening files

Comment: installed with sudo apt install hdfview. no error is printed. the file is simply not opened. can you install and try to open a file? I say it is a 17.04 problem because it was working on 16.04

Comment: Same here - to be more precise, the GUI starts, opens the file, but on the root element of the hdf5 hierarchy is visible in the GUI... So not usable. It works fine on 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem here. I could solve it by installing the [HDFView-3.0.0](https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/). It is a beta version but at least works.
You need to create an account in the website, then, you can download the pre-built binary and you just need to follow the instructions (as in readme):

To install HDFView for Linux, copy HDFView-3.0.0-Linux.sh to where you want to install HDFView and:

1. Execute HDFView-3.0.0-Linux.sh
2. Follow prompts (you need to accept the license)
3. Execute HDFView/3.0.0/hdfview.sh to run HDFView

In my case, the java version was wrong, so, when I execute the step 3 above, I received the message:

`/home/Downloads/HDFView-3.0-centos7/HDFView-3.0.0-Linux/HDFView/3.0.0/jre/bin/java: line 5: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.99-2.6.5.0.el7_2.x86_64/jre-abrt/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Then, I edited this file (in line 5) to point to the correct java path, in my case `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`.

I hope that works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Easy install(version hdf5-1.10.1) here:
https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src

and configuration here: https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL_Cygwin.txt

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.